# The view 'Index' was not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller. When I call it's method `AddProductToComparsionList` via Postman, I.m getting error "*The view 'Index' was not found*". How can I fix this? Other controllers works fine.

```
public class ProductComparsion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class ProductComparsionVM
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class MapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<ProductComparsion, ProductComparsionVM, ProductComparsionEVM>();
    }
}

public class ComparsionController : CmsController
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IInternalMapper _mapper;

    public ComparsionController(IInternalMapper mapper, AppDbContext dbContext) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _productRepo = productRepo;
        _userManager = (CmsUserManager<AppUser>)userManager;
    }
    // Error
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string code)
    {
        var productComparsion = await _dbContext.ProductsComparsion
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
        var vm = _mapper.Map<IReadOnlyCollection<ProductComparsionVM>>(productComparsion);

        return View(vm);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProductToComparsionList([FromBody] List<int> productIds, int categoryId, int? listId)
{
    return Json(await _productRepo.AddProductToComparsionList(productIds, categoryId, listId));
}
```

Comment: What's the url you are calling from postman?

Comment: `AddProductToComparsionList` is part of which controller?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya 
This url https://localhost:5001/Comparsion/AddProductToComparsionList, ComparsionController

Comment: Are you able to debug the code? Code inside method `AddProductToComparsionList` is executed?

Comment: I can debug it and this code is not executed. When I tried to test endpoints (AddPdoduct, DeleteProduct etc.), I called it inside `Index` and returned null from `Index`. Now I know that endpoints works and need to be able to call it from Posman